# How to add buttons to datagridview cells not entire column

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

How do you add a button to cells in a row and not the entire column in a datagridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I endded up doing was stacking a DataGridView on top of another one. I turned off the border, gridlines, and scrollbars. Then create dynamic button columns to match the main datagridview with only one row of buttons. Then I used the ColumnWidthChanged event handler to resize both the DataGridViews together. Anyway's this was my workaround for now.

Answer (score 2):

I think Adrian's answer was close. Try something like this.

```
if ((string)table.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value == "I should be a button") {
   // you can add formatting or values to the button before assigning it here
   table.Rows[0].cells[0] = new DataGridViewButtonCell();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the best answer if found here:
[Hide gridview button](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f82ec651-6b22-44b0-8ead-15796387424f/hideing-and-showing-a-datagridviewbuttoncell?forum=winformsapplications). All you need to do is to add a DataGridViewButtonCell where you want buttons, and DataGridViewTextBoxCell where you do not. The column has to be DataGridViewButton type.

Answer (score 0):

See this similar post in SO, probably helps

[adding control to gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418379/how-do-i-programmatically-add-a-button-to-a-gridview-and-assign-it-to-a-specific)

In case Win Form, Check this MSDN post

[Column Types in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxt3k60s.aspx)

OR this code project post ... though it gives example of adding a image button

[DataGridView Image Button Cell](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/DGV_ImageButtonCell.aspx)

@tmax In that case you can probably put your button creation code in `GridView_RowCreated` event like below

```
void GridView_RowCreated(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {   
     if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
      {   
           //Button creation code here        
      } 
  }
```

Comment: From what I've seen in the links it shows the entire column havint the same type. I would like to add buttun to the top row only.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = new Button();
    //btn attributes
    dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value = new Button();
}
```

try something like this.

Comment: off course, ...Cells[x]... you know the number of the column.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work either. The result in the cell was "System.Windows.Forms.Button, Text:". I am pretty sure you have to set the entire column to the Button DataType. I was hoping for an alternative but no avail yet.

Comment: You are right, it's not working like this. If you don't have a too big application, try to port it to WPF. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
 DataGridViewButtonColumn dataGridViewButtonColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
        dataGridViewButtonColumn.Name = "Select";
        dataGridViewButtonColumn.HeaderText = "Select";
  
        dataGridViewButtonColumn.ReadOnly = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dataGridViewButtonColumn);
```

Answer (score 0):

After assigning data source to gridviewCTRL. you can add new column with button with below code.

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn startbtn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
startbtn.Name = "Action";
startbtn.Text = "Start";
startbtn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue=true;
int columnIndex = 6;
gridviewCTRL.Columns.Insert(columnIndex, startbtn);
```

This will add the button to each and every row at define column index.
if you want to render condition the **AccessibleObject**, then you can do something similar to below.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow rowdata in gridviewCTRL.Rows)
{
    // this is just an example in my case i am checking a previous column value
    if (rowdata.Cells[5].Value=="XYZ")
    {  
          rowdata.Cells[6] = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
    }
}
```

This way you can dynamically render/ showing the control in the GridView in Winforms c#.

The above code simple update the cell with new cell. We can't remove button from the cell nor remove whole, so instead we can initial a new cell that will override the button visibility.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this will help but you can also consider using TableLayoutPanel.

Refer: [Winforms TableLayoutPanel adding rows programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142873/winforms-tablelayoutpanel-adding-rows-programatically)