# The click event doesn't call when i add Button to GridView's Cell from code behind

Tags: asp.net

I use below code for add Button to GridView's Cell from code behind,but when i click on each button that i add,the click event(lnk_Click) doesn't call and button hides after i click on it.how can i solve this problem?

```
//aspx
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" GridLines="None" Width="940px"
      OnSelectedIndexChanged="grid_SelectedIndexChanged"
      onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="gridview">
       <Columns>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="...">
               <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:Panel ID="pnlSteps" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
               </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
       </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>

    //Code behind
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                Panel pnl = (Panel)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("pnlSteps");
                LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
                lnk.Text = "...";
                pnl.Controls.Add(lnk);
                lnk.Click += new EventHandler(lnk_Click);
            }//for
    ...

    protected void lnk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    //...
    }
```

//Edit

I fill the gridview with below code

```
//dsSet is DataSet that i fill it with data from Database
DataTable dtt = new DataTable();

        dtt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("status", typeof(string)));
        dtt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("finantial", typeof(string)));
        dtt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("phone", typeof(string)));
        dtt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("name", typeof(string)));
        dtt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("code", typeof(string)));

        for (int i = 0; i < dsSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dtt.NewRow();

            dr[0]=...;
            dr[1]=...;
            dr[2]=...;
            dr[3]=...;
            dr[4]=...;

            dtt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }//for
        GridView1.DataSource = dtt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: hi refer this for your answer
[click here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418379/how-do-i-programmatically-add-a-button-to-a-gridview-and-assign-it-to-a-specific

Comment: Could you please post the code where you're populating the grid view with data?

Comment: @SAK:i edited the question,please help me that i solve this big! problem

Comment: have you put the above code in if(!ispostback) condition?.

Comment: i use this code when user click on a button

Answer (score 1):

because the button is inside the `gridview` so you can't get its click event in `onclick` but you have to use [GridView.RowCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx) and use `commandname` in the button

**Edit**

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="AddButton" runat="server" 
      CommandName="commandName" 

      Text="command" />
  </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

code behind:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, 
  GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.CommandName == "commandName")
  {
     // add your code
  }

}
```

Comment: I set command to Linkbutton (`lnk.CommandName = "CommandName";`) and set RowCommand event to GridView (`OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"`) but again RowCommand doesn't call

Comment: please check this link , for more info. about how to use GridView.RowCommand Event  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx