# How to add a href for a button/link in ASP.NET GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have an ASP.NET web app that processes some data from other sites and displays the information in a gridview. I don't know how many rows that gridview is going to have, nor how many columns.

In this gridview I have a templatefield which I used to add a Checkbox.
The rest of the columns are added using a DataTable that I bind to this gridview. The problem now is that after 10 columns, I have an URL which I want to display as a button, or a link. After this link I have x nr of columns.

How do I add this URL which is resting between static columns and dynamic columns, in a GridView with dynamic rows ?

I tried writing a href=link.. in the DataTable but it displays it as text.
I found an article that suggested something with HtmlDecode, but for that to work I would need to use boundfields which set the htmlencode = false..or something like that.

Is there any way of doing this ? or should I just move the link in the itemtemplate that has the checkbox as well and try to set it there ?

[image]

Comment: Could you post a few pictures of your current view, and maybe what you'd like it to look like?  That would help clarify a lot.

Comment: it would also be helpful to see how you bind the data

Comment: Added an image. The top table is what I have now. The bottom one is what I would like it to be. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `OnRowDataBound` for that. It will insert extra cells into the GridView. You could also insert extra column into the DataTable *before* binding it to the GridView.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //header
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        //add 6 cells
        for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
        {
            TableHeaderCell headerCell = new TableHeaderCell();

            if (i == 6)
            {
                headerCell.Text = "URL";
            }
            else
            {
                headerCell.Text = "Static " + i;
            }

            //add the new cell to the gridview
            e.Row.Cells.AddAt(i, headerCell);
        }
    }

    //normal row
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //cast the current row to a datarowview
        DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

        //add 6 cells
        for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
        {
            TableCell cell = new TableCell();

            if (i == 6)
            {
                cell.Text = string.Format("<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"{0}\">{0}</a>", row["myURL"]);
            }
            else
            {
                cell.Text = "Enter stuff here...";
            }

            //add the new cell to the gridview
            e.Row.Cells.AddAt(i, cell);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have done like you suggested and the button shows up in the GridView, but when I click on it, it dissappears. Do you know what I can do so that it doesn't update the table ? I'm guessing I should do something like if(!Page.IsPostBack){..}, but I don't exactly know where I should put this

Comment: Manage to make the button not postback by adding "return=false" in the OnClientClick(). It works. Thank you !

Comment: I've just found out that elements added dynamically on RowDataBound, only persist until the next postback. I have some other buttons on my page, which shouldn't postback anything. I have some export to excel buttons for example and when I click on them the dynamically added button dissappears. What could I do to stop this behaviour ? Do I need to move all my buttons in javascript ? If I could, I would move the "add button" part in Page Load so this wouldn't happen, but I can't. I need it to by dynamic. Any solutions ? Thanks !

Comment: You need to recreate dynamic controls on every postback. So move the binding of the gridview outside `if (!IsPostBack)` check.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **MatchGrid_RowDataBound** method to look over the columns and add the buttons as you need.
Here is an example of how to add a button on RowDataBound:
[How do I programmatically add a button to a gridview and assign it to a specific code-behind function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418379/how-do-i-programmatically-add-a-button-to-a-gridview-and-assign-it-to-a-specific)

Comment: I tried doing it like this in RowDataBound: LinkButton artLink = new LinkButton();
            artLink.OnClientClick = "window.open('" + currentUrl + "');";
            artLink.Text = "View article on " + e.Row.Cells[3].Text;
            e.Row.Cells[12].Controls.Add(artLink); //The link showed up but it only works once. After I click it, it dissappears